# Python TkInter bind breaking

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

I have a simple GUI which uses key binds - something like this.

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.bind('3', self.do_bar)
        master.bind('9', self.load_new_config)

        self.load_config()

        if not self.conf:
            self.load_new_config()
        else:
            self.load_data()

    def load_config(self):
        try:
            self.conf = #get stuff from known file
        except FailedToGetStuff:
            self.conf = None

    def load_new_config(self):
        path = askopenfilename(initialdir='~')
        self.conf = #get stuff from file in path
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self):
        #get data from self.conf, process and display

    def do_bar(self):
        #do stuff with displayed data

if __name__ == "__main__"
    root = Tk()
    Foo(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Now, this works just fine when load_config() finds what it was looking for. I can use the binds and even after using '9' and loading new config, everything works.
Problem is, if load_config() fails, self.conf gets set to None and load_new_conf gets called from `__init__`, the binds are no longer operational.

I figured out that the problem is caused by tkFileDialog.askopenfilename() being called from within `__init__`. What I don't understand is why this happens and how to get around it.

Comment: Have you verified that the root eindow has focus when the bindings stop working? It could just be that your app is losing focus.

Comment: Using `master.focus_set()` at the end of `__init__` to force focus on root did not solve the issue.

Comment: Try this: `foo = Foo(root)`

Comment: In the main block? If so, no change in behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        master.bind('<KeyPress-3>', self.do_bar)
        master.bind('<KeyPress-9>', self.load_new_config)

        self.load_config()

        if not self.conf:
            master.after(1, self.load_new_config)
        else:
            self.load_data()

    def load_config(self):
        try:
            self.conf = None#get stuff from known file
        except FailedToGetStuff:
            self.conf = None

    def load_new_config(self, e = 0):
        path = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='~')
        self.conf = None#get stuff from file in path
        self.load_data()

    def load_data(self, e = 0):
        pass
        #get data from self.conf, process and display

    def do_bar(self, e = 0):
        print 1
        #do stuff with displayed data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    Foo(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yes, this is how I did it in the end - just wait for user input. That is, however, not my intended behaviour, I want the program to ask for new config automatically.

Comment: Edited it. now it works for me on startup, too. starting the dialog when the mainloop is started was the key: `master.after(1, self.load_new_config())`

Comment: Thank you very much, this works. However, I would suggest one change: `master.after(1, self.load_new_config)` instead of `master.after(1, self.load_new_config())`. Otherwise it won't wait the specified time and the function will be called immediately.